# Is there a Java library to access the native Windows API?

Tags: java, windows, winapi

Is there a Java library to access the native Windows API? Either with COM or JNI.

Comment: i wonder if this java native library could traced the current printerjob info including 'number of copies' somewhere....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could try these two, I have seen success with both.

http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net

> The Java/Win32 integration project
>   (Jawin) is a free, open source
>   architecture for  interoperation
>   between Java and components exposed
>   through Microsoft's Component Object
>   Model (COM) or through Win32 Dynamic
>   Link Libraries (DLLs).

https://github.com/twall/jna/

> JNA provides Java programs easy access
>   to native shared libraries (DLLs on
>   Windows) without writing anything but
>   Java code—no JNI or native code is
>   required. This functionality is
>   comparable to Windows' Platform/Invoke
>   and Python's ctypes. Access is dynamic
>   at runtime without code generation.
>
> JNA allows you to call directly into
>   native functions using natural Java
>   method invocation. The Java call looks
>   just like it does in native code. Most
>   calls require no special handling or
>   configuration; no boilerplate or
>   generated code is required.

Also read up here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

> The Java Native Interface (JNI) is a
>   programming framework that allows Java
>   code running in a Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM) to call and to be called[1](https://github.com/twall/jna/) by
>   native applications (programs specific
>   to a hardware and operating system
>   platform) and libraries written in
>   other languages, such as C, C++ and
>   assembly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access

> Java Native Access provides Java
>   programs easy access to native shared
>   libraries without using the Java
>   Native Interface. JNA's design aims to
>   provide native access in a natural way
>   with a minimum of effort. No
>   boilerplate or generated glue code is
>   required.

Answer (score 5):

[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/#getting_started) is pretty nice. I'm just a beginner and I found it very easy. Works not only for the Win32 API but for almost any other DLL.

Answer (score 3):

[Jacob](http://danadler.com/jacob/) is quite good on the COM side (but it's *real* COM - like you write in C++ - if you are familiar with true COM programming, then Jacob is a snap to use)

Comment: Not trying to nitpick, but COM exposes services through a **C** interface.

Answer (score 1):

[JNIWrapper](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/index.jsf) or [ConfyJ](http://www.teamdev.com/comfyj/) from from TeamDev.

Answer (score 1):

One more option is [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sf.net). It has a native binding layer that aims to be compatible with [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/) (the native binding format used in dot net). See [examples](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/nativebinding.html) for more information. Its a little early days so YMMV.

(full disclosure: i work on the project).

Yet another option is [JFFI](https://github.com/wmeissner/jffi) - this is used in jruby and jython to interact with native libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com/)