# Remote file transfer between windows system using Java

Tags: java, window, copy

How to do remote file transfer between windows system using Java? In more detail, these windows systems are in same domain. I want Java API, which can transfer files (ASCII and Binary) between windows system by using assigned username, password, domain name and source and destination file location.

Comment: What user/pass? ActiveDirectory or Windows-Users or your own brew?

Comment: Windows credential of each machine, so that user can access that machine. For every machine it may have different username and password. But while copying we can specify individual user to perform operations.

Comment: Have thought about using some SCP library? Did you do some research? Talking about Domains, I guess you want to use TCP/IP or at least some network transport?

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199624/scp-via-java

Comment: @Fildor : How can i use `JSch` over windows?

Answer (score 2):

Use Sockets to connect (previous configuration by IP) to a SocketServer and transfer the files.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this, but I'd say you'll need to use the native Windows API to achieve this.

You could do it with [JNI and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13093/C-method-calls-within-a-Java-program). C# has `File.Copy` (see example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ffebef9c-a063-46e6-8307-2f73bbf688b7/)) that makes use of native [CopyFile function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363851%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Alternatively, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606820/is-there-a-java-library-to-access-the-native-windows-api) question on SO.

Hope this gives you some leads.