# Create shortcut in windows programmatically

Tags: java, windows, filesystems, shortcut

Is there a way to create link in windows?
I found samples that use `VBScript` or one has to do download `Shortcut.exe`.
I need a simple solution. Is that possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606820/is-there-a-java-library-to-access-the-native-windows-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java

Comment: You can run VB script from Java.

Comment: If the app. has a GUI, the best option is usually to install it using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix, and provides support for desktop shortcuts, start menu items and file associations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had to use `Shortcut.exe` to create shortcut but actually what I needed was a `HardLink` to a folder but `Shortcut.exe` would create a `SoftLink`.
Eventually I used `junction.exe` to create the `HardLink`.
Check this post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-windows

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem, so i wrote library for parsing and creating .lnk files. It does not use VBScripts or JNI, java code only. See my [Github](https://github.com/BlackOverlord666/mslinks).

Creating shortcuts: `ShellLink.createLink("targetfile", "linkfile.lnk")`. You can also set up most parameters of the link. See details and examples in repo.

Probably this question is not actual already, but i hope it will be helpfull for people who will find this topic in Google.

Comment: This `mslinks` library works well.  Only potential downside to users is compiling it by hand (To the author of the library, I do recommend offering a jar download via `mslinks/releases`).  Works very well for simply linking a `.exe` to a target location.  As illustrated in the comment above, the code is a one-liner after the library/api has been imported.

Comment: @BlackOverlord this is great! Do you know of a way to set the shortcut to "Run as administrator" by default as well?

Answer (score -4):

I suggest you to create a shortcut manually and then copy it programatically into the desktop folder.
c:\users\desktop