# how to print list of files selected in windows console in java

Tags: java, windows, contextmenu

I have the requirement to print the full path and file names of files selected in windows directory.

the approach I have taken is

```
1. create key in registry to give option in context menu
2. attached the context menu option to execute my java program
```

now the issue I have , 
I want to select a few files ,

```
1. then right click on it
2. then execute my java program 
3. and have the list of files selected in my java program as an input
```

i am not able to achieve point 3

any guidance how to approach it or better alternative

Answer (score 1):

I think there is 2 possible approaches here.

1. You can custom *Send to* context menu, it supports passing multiple selected files. I prefer this one. It's quite simple to implement.

   For example:

   **Ex.java**

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class Ex {
       public static void main(String[] args)
               throws IOException {
           for (String argument : args) {
               System.out.println(argument);
           }
           System.in.read();
       }
   }
   ```

   Compile it to `Ex.class`.

   Create a shortcut named `Test Send To` in `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` point to:

   ```
   "path\to\java.exe" -cp "path\to\Ex.class folder" Ex
   ```

   Now try selecting multiple files and then right-click `Send To > Test Send To`, you will see the list of selected files onscreen.
2. You can implement *interprocess communication* to tell the existing instance that you want to add more files to proceed.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Please check my updated answer. I just add a small sample for point 1.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Sorry for my unclear explanation. I mean to create a shortcut whose target is `"path\to\java.exe" -cp "path\to\Ex.class folder" Ex`. ![Here is the image](http://i.imgur.com/cY0w9Du.png)

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri' Maybe your problem is still. Here I can find some related posts: [Create shortcut programatically in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629034/create-shortcut-in-windows-programmatically) [Custom "Send to" context menu"](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/customize-the-windows-vista-send-to-menu/)