# Call GetLogicalDrives from Java

Tags: java, winapi

I need to get information about system drives using WinAPI. On MSDN I found functin `DWORD WINAPI GetLogicalDrives(void);` located in `kernel32.dll`.
Can I call it without using JNA/JNI? How should I declare this function in Java?

Like:

```
static {
    System.load("C:/Windows/System32/kernel32.dll");
}

native SomeClass GetLogicalDrives(???);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SomeClass info = GetLogicalDrives(???);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606820/is-there-a-java-library-to-access-the-native-windows-api Have a look at this post

Comment: @SaileshD so I can't do this with pure Java (or it is very difficult) without third-party library?