# How can I add controller/gamepad support into a java program?

Tags: java, gamepad

Im currently making a small game and I would like to include Ps4/xbox/gamepad controller support in it. I cannot seem to find many resources on how to actually implement this so I was wondering what the best way to do this would be in Java?

I have tried searching ways to do this, but again have not found anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that JInput - https://jinput.github.io/jinput/ - might help you with what you are trying to do. It looks a bit stale and I have not tried it, so I have no idea if it even works with modern Java.

In short, due to Java's cross-platform approach you are going to need a library that allows you to discover and use input devices on various platforms.

If you focus on Windows, you could access native Windows libraries, as explained e.g. in [this question about Java and native Windows libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606820/is-there-a-java-library-to-access-the-native-windows-api).

If you want to create a web application, then with (quite) some work you could probably [make use of the Gamepad API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Gamepad_API).